# Need to understand std::remove with vector.erase

Tags: c++, vector, stl-algorithm

I came across an article that stated that the best method of removing items for vectors is using the erase-remove idiom which is as follows

```
//say vec = 1963,1923,1900,1963,1967;
vector.erase(std::remove(vec.begin(),vec.end(),1963),vec.end());
```

Now from what I understand is that vec.erase takes in two parameters the first and the last iterator. The range includes all the elements between first and last. I wanted to know how std::remove would give that single iterator range if the value to be removed is present at different indexes in the vector. I want to know how std::remove works with vector.erase

Comment: remove moves the range so that the removed elements are at the end and returns an iterator that points to the first removed element. By giving the second iterator to end, it erases all of them.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`remove` doesn't give a range. It just gives one iterator. The range you pass to `erase` starts at that iterator and ends at `vec.end()`, which is your second argument.

`remove` works by rearranging the sequence so that all the elements to be removed are at the end, of the sequence, and it returns the iterator that points to the first of those to-be-removed elements.

(So `remove` doesn't actually *remove* anything - but the content of the to-be-removed elements is indeterminate and should not be accessed anyway.)

Comment: I tried explaining this and deleted my post as sounding silly. std::remove doesn't remove! It moves / rearranges!

Comment: Yes. `std::remove` doesn't remove. I wish it had a better name. I'm pretty sure I'm not the only one.